# Terms in loop contains their sum

Tags: r, loops

I would like to write a code that generates `3 x 1` vector `y` according to following rule (The small numbers are selected for simplicity):

[image]

Here `x` is a `3 x 1` vector. According to the rule, for an update of `y`, I need sum of all `y`’s.

An attemp to code with an arbitrary `x`:

```
x <- c(2,3,1)
y <- c(0,0,0)

for(i in 1:5){
  for(j in 1:3){
    y[j] <- x[j] + y[j] + sum(y)
  }
}
```

This code is not appropriate because it computes `sum(b)` term by term. 
The inner loop indicates something like this:

```
y[1] = x[1] + 0 = 2
y[2] = x[2] + 2 = 5
y[3] = x[3] + 2 + 5 = 8
```

It is not appropriate because `sum(y)` term contains one term for `y[1]`, two terms for `y[2]`, three terms for `y[3]`. But I think `sum(y)` should be `2 + 5 + 8 = 15` for each iteration, `y[1], y[2], y[3]`,  according to the rule given above. Moreover this procedure should be repeated for a certain times (here 5 times shown by the outer loop). At each time of outer loop, only one `sum(y)` term will be computed for all three iteration of inner loop and it will be put as `sum(y)` term for each `j`.

How should I code this?

Comment: your formula is not very clear: you are using the index `j` twice. What should the scope of the sum be?

Comment: Is 2,5,8 the correct answer?

Comment: the whole term is always 0 since you start vector for y is 0 ???

Comment: Unclear what `i` is in your loop since your formula only uses `j`... and where does the `1:5` come from for `i`?

Comment: There is some kind of loop for y_j (it references itself) here and I can only see this to be true if y is always 0.

Comment: Sorry for typo in the rule. I corrected `*` to `+` and summation is over `k`. `i` is, actually, for convergence in the original code. This is a code that have a similar problem in my original code. The main problem: I need to use whole `y_j` terms in the `sum(y)` term in my iterations.

Comment: With the updates, if I delete the outer `i` loop, I get 2, 5, 8. I think that's *not* what you want, but I have no idea what you do want. What is the correct answer, and why? Something about the `sum(y)`... you maybe want to compute it in the outer loop, not the inner loop? If I move `sy = sum(y)` to the first line of the outer loop and replace `+ sum(y)` with `+ sy` in the inner loop I get 2, 3, 1 for the first iteration. Can you please share what the right answer is supposed to be?

Comment: @ Gregor thanks. I'm sorry I could not explain it smoothly, but your comment is very useful. This code I wrote just reflects a tiny part of my problem. By the way, I must use loops because my original problem is not appropriate for vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating this. Vectorize the inner-loop away:

```
> x <- c(2,3,1)
> y <- c(0,0,0)
> for(j in 1:5) y <- x + y + sum(y)
> y
[1] 682 687 677
```

This approach only computes `sum(y)` once per iteration, which is what you seem to want. As an added benefit, adding vectors in a single operation is much faster than adding them component-wise in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work

```
myfun <- function(x, y, i) {
    y[i] <- x[i] + sum(y)
    if (i < length(x)) {
        myfun(x, y, i+1)
    } else {
        return(y)
    }
}

x <- c(2, 3, 1)
y <- rep(0, length(x))
myfun(x, y, 1)
# [1] 2 5 8

x <- c(2, 3, 1, 5)
y <- rep(0, length(x))
myfun(x, y, 1)
# [1] 2 5 8 20
```